# Why is brace bracket required in arity-1 method invocation?

Tags: scala

I was getting an error when I was writing code like `foo.map(case Foobar(x,y) => something)`. Later I discovered that I have to use brace brackets to wrap the anonymous function (`case Foobar(x,y) => something`). Below is a demo from the scala REPL:

```
scala> val a = List(((1, 2),3), ((4,5),6))
a: List[((Int, Int), Int)] = List(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6))

scala> a.map({case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c)})
res0: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6))

scala> a.map(case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c))
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
a.map(case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c))
```

Note that the brace brackets are removed in the last command compared to the one above.

So, what is the reason for this behavior? Why can't scala compiler infer the anonymous function without the brace brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because without the curly braces you're just creating an instance of `FunctionN`, however with the curly braces you're creating an instance of `PartialFunction` which allows you to use `case` with a destructuring clause.

You can check out the docs for `PartialFunction` [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) which shows a pretty straightforward example:

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, Any] = { case _ => 1/0 }
```

Note that this behaviour is currently seen as unwanted and will be fixed in Dotty. With Dotty your function would become this:

```
a.map(((a,b),c) => (a,b,c))
```

For more information on that you can check out slide 37 in [this presentation.](http://www.slideshare.net/Odersky/scala-days-nyc-2016)

Comment: Yeah, Dotty will be really awesome. Soon!